# Android multitouch in supported devices

Tags: android, multi-touch

let's say I'd like to have an image view in my app with zoom
is it possible to add multitouch event listeners on phones that do support multi touch (API 7+), while on older phones show zoom buttons?

Can this be done in a single version of the app or do I need multiple app versions and multiple APKs?

Comment: yeah but you have to use Reflections for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need multiple APK in this case.

You can check availability of the multitouch in the code:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 7) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean hasMultitouch = 
        pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH);
    if (hasMultitouch) {
        // set multitouch event listeners
    } else {
        // set zoom buttons
    }
} else {
    // set zoom buttons
}
```

You can get `PackageManager` from your activity (service) without using `context`: `PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();`

There are three types of multitouch you can check.

- [FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH) - basic two-finger gesture detection.
- [FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT) - tracking two or more fingers fully independently.
- [FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND) - tracking a full hand of fingers fully independently - that is, 5 or more simultaneous independent pointers.

**Upd:** you must check API version before multitouch availability check. `FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH` available only from API 7. I've updated the code sample.

Comment: what will I do when I find out multitouch is available? Won't the app crash on API 4 when I will use multitouch API 7 methods and classes in the code?

Comment: It will crash of course, but it doesn't needed to use multitouch API 7 methods on API 4. You have proposed solution already: if multitouch doesn't supported then don't use it and show zoom buttons.

Comment: but the code will be compiled with API 7 methods, what will happen on devices with API 4? Won't they refuse to install the app?

Comment: While this code (API 7 methods) doesn't called, everything will be OK. Anyway you can check how it works in emulator.

Comment: Shouldn't I check also for FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT and JAZZHAND? I mean, if the system has DISTINCT or HAZZHAND, does it automatically has FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH?

Comment: @Pavel Alexeev As far as I understand, FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH is sufficient. You should check also for FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT or FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND only if you need one of this multitouch modes.

Comment: @Sergey Your code won't work on devices at API levels 4 and below, because hasSystemFeature was introduced in API level 5. (You'll get a verification error from dalvik VM at runtime.) To get around this, you can use the delayed classloader trick or something similar: http://blog.javia.org/android-application-backwards-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

you can check out your api level at the start up of your app and set the correct listeners and buttons on this information.

may be [this site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) is usefull for you

example:

```
    if(Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 7)
    {
        //add multi touch listeners
    }
    else
    {
        // add zoom buttons
    }
```

Comment: I think that just to check API level is not enough. There are devices with API 7+ but without multitouch.