# Programmatically find how many fingers in multitouch Android device supports

Tags: android, multi-touch

On Android, it is possible to check programmatically if the device supports multitouch or not wth http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH.

Is it also possible to check exactly how many fingers the device can recognize in multitouch? E.g. from what I know, a 2-finger multitouch is supported starting with 2.x, but 3-finger multitouch from 4.0. But our customer reports having some new devices with 4.x which still don't support 3 fingers, which makes a simple check against the version of Android OS useless.

A possible solution would be to store in some dictionary for each device which number of fingers it supports max, but with 1k+ devices out there and new ones constantly appearing it's not viable.

Any solution?

EDIT: In fact I just found that the issue reported by the customer was a device issue on HTC One series. See http://www.mobiflip.de/htc-one-serie-multitouch-beschraenkung-aufheben-tipp/ The user has to turn the device-specific gestures recognition in settings to get 5+ fingers working. So, the device would probably even show 5+ fingers support. I guess we will just check for the device's model and show special popup for it telling the user to turn that HTC-specific setting off.

Comment: As shown in the answers, you cannot determine whether a device supports some arbitrary number of touch points (e.g., 3). You need to develop your app to support the different buckets, or use `<uses-feature>` to limit your app to only run on devices residing in those same buckets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way of obtaining the exact number of *pointers* supported by a device. I don't want to reinvent the wheel here, so I'd like to share a similar problem and a great answer here: [Android multitouch in supported devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244656/1820695).

To summarize, notable is the method `PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()` which allows you to find out in which multitouch-support category does current device belong. Useful feature codes include:

- `FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH` - basic support for 2 *pointers*
- `FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT` - support for 2+ *independent pointers*.
- `FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND` - support for 5+ *independent pointers*.

Comment: I've been there too. In the end I've managed to modify the UI and gestures to just differentiate the cases of *2 pointers* and *2 independent pointers*. Hope you'll figure it out too.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: there is no way to differentiate the case when the device supports exactly 2 independent pointers and not 3 from the case when the device supports 3 or more pointers?

Comment: @iseeall quite right, but change *3 or more* to *3 or 4*. If the device supports 5+, it should include (return `true` for) the *jazzhand* feature.

Comment: In fact I just found that the issue reported by the customer was a device issue on HTC One series. See http://www.mobiflip.de/htc-one-serie-multitouch-beschraenkung-aufheben-tipp/. The user has to turn the device-specific gestures recognition in settings to get 5+ fingers working.

Comment: @iseeall huh, thanks for sharing :) I myself have had several HTC phones and their additions to bare Android OS were (for me) always troublesome. And buggy.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking just for MULTITOUCH, you want to check for [FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND)