# Android Multitouch on 2.3.x

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a game and a basic requirement for multiplayer is multitouch (two buttons being pressed at the same time) . Without it, the game makes no sense. So I am trying to make it work properly for a few days and I came to some conclusions.

I will show my test class, if I make it work there, implementing that in my game is a piece of cake. User @jboi wrote me this piece of code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TEST", "Begin onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("TEST", "End   onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    findViewById(R.id.upperTouchable).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.lowerTouchable).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
}

private boolean lowerIsTouched = false;
private boolean upperIsTouched = false;

private void setInfo() {
    if(lowerIsTouched && upperIsTouched)
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info)).setText("both touched");
    else if(lowerIsTouched)
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info)).setText("only lower is touched");
    else if(upperIsTouched)
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info)).setText("only upper is touched");
    else
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info)).setText("non is touched");

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lowerTouchable)).setText(lowerIsTouched? "touched":"not touched");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.upperTouchable)).setText(upperIsTouched? "touched":"not touched");
}

private class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.lowerTouchable)
                lowerIsTouched = true;
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.upperTouchable)
                upperIsTouched = true;
            setInfo();
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.lowerTouchable)
                lowerIsTouched = false;
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.upperTouchable)
                upperIsTouched = false;
            setInfo();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
android:text="Non touched"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/upperTouchable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Not touched"
    android:background="#FFF0F0F0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lowerTouchable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Not touched"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tested this on several devices.
It works on: Htc One (4.2.2), Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.3), Samsung Galaxy S3(4.1.2.)
(when i press both buttons -> both are pressed)
It doesn't work on:Sony Xperia Arc S(2.3.4.) and Alcatel One Touch(2.3.6.)
(when i press both buttons -> only the first button is pressed)
So I came to conclusion that the android version where multitouch support starts is between 2.4 and 4.1, but that's not true, because it's been added in 2.2.

I have 24 hours to solve this. Optionally, I could make my app compatibile only with 4.0+, but I would really like to make it work on most Android phones. My question is: How do I make this code work on 2.3-4.1, because I'm sure it can work (other apps have functional multitouch on those phones). Completely rewriting my code is also an option. I have tried working with ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, that also failed on "lower version" phones. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first one, you need check if your device have support for multitouch, that is very important and the features configured.
You can red [this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322480/programmatically-find-how-many-fingers-in-multitouch-android-device-supports)

You can check availability of the multitouch in the code:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 7) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean hasMultitouch = 
        pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH);
    if (hasMultitouch) {
        // set multitouch event listeners
    } else {
        // set zoom buttons
    }
} else {
    // set zoom buttons
}
```

You can get PackageManager from your activity (service) without using context: PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

There are three types of multitouch you can check.

```
[FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH][2] - basic two-finger gesture detection.
[FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT][3] - tracking two or more fingers fully independently.
[FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND][4] - tracking a full hand of fingers fully independently - that is, 5 or more simultaneous independent pointers.
```

Comment: I am not at home now, I'll try it. But there are apps with multitouch that work on Arc S, so I guess that means Arc S supports it, I don't need to check? (e.g. Wizard Wars from play store)