# Android multi touch can't detect 3 fingers

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am trying to detect three fingers in the same time on HTC One M10.
There is no motion called on any of this cases.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: return "Down";
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: return "Move";
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: return "Pointer Down";
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: return "Up";
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: return "Pointer Up";
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE: return "Outside";
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: return "Cancel";
```

I download some apps and they also cant detect 3 at the same time but they recognized two.
How can I recognized only two if the motions not call.
Thanks.

**update** After chacking agian the case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE didn't call.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this app to check how much fingers my screen supports - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easylabs.multitouch.

After you receive exact number of touches your phone supports, you can detect multitouch by counting actions ACTION_DOWN (+1) and ACTION_UP(-1). With that counter you can always know how many fingers are touched to screen at this moment.

Link to answer [Programmatically find how many fingers in multitouch Android device supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322480/programmatically-find-how-many-fingers-in-multitouch-android-device-supports).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but how can I detect 2 from 3 points if all I want is to place all together at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean "to place all together at the same time"? How many fingers touched do you think you need?

Comment: If I put 3 fingers together at the same time it doesn't call "ACTION_DOWN" but with other devices it calls. In the app from google play it also doesn't detect 3 fingers when I put all together at the same time it recognized just two of my fingers on the screen.

Comment: You can't actually put even 2 fingers at the same time exactly. It's just impossible to be so accurate. So if your device is able to handle multitouch - 3 consecutive ACTION_DOWN must be called.

Comment: I update my question agian, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Try to start with a sample in Android Studio. You need to File -> New -> Import Sample -> Basic Multitouch. If it works on your HTC you can view the code and do the same.

Comment: Is it possible to find out what is the max fingers the device can handle at the same time you touch?

Comment: Added a link to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off HTC gesture on your device.