# How many touch I can get from android base smartphone (like Samsung A7)

Tags: android, multi-touch, smartphone

I want to know how many points I can get using the android base touchscreen on mobile phones.

If you know there are references also please share it with me.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244656/1820695)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to count the number of fingers on the screen at a time.

```
if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "support multitouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    findViewById(R.id.cl_main).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
                Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "number of fingers " + pointerCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

To check whether the device supports more than 5 fingers, use this code

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "More than 5 fingers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to get points but I don't know how many maximum points we can get? Because if you can get for example 200 points you cannot test by your fingers at least.

Comment: No, you can't get that information, since it varies on every device. There's no way to find that